# RegEx for split a string with comma ignoring comma with a space

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to write a regular expression to split a string with comma but not comma with space.I wrote one , but it did not work out.

E.g:

```
String testString = "CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE,IRAN, ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF,KOREA, DEMOCRATIC PEOPLE S REPUBLIC OF,NEPAL,NEW ZEALAND,SRI LANKA";
```

Expected Result:

1. CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE
2. IRAN, ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF
3. KOREA, DEMOCRATIC PEOPLE S REPUBLIC OF
4. NEPAL
5. NEW ZEALAND
6. SRI LANKA

My code:

```
public class TestRegEx {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString = "CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE,IRAN, ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF,KOREA, DEMOCRATIC PEOPLE S REPUBLIC OF,NEPAL,NEW ZEALAND,SRI LANKA";
        String[] output = testString.split("([,][^(,\\s)])+");
        for (String country : output) {
            System.out.println(country);
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

1. CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE
2. RAN, ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF
3. OREA, DEMOCRATIC PEOPLE S REPUBLIC OF
4. EPAL
5. EW ZEALAND
6. RI LANKA

Answer (score 4):

```
,(?!\s)
```

Explanation:

Match any comma that is not followed by whitespace.

See it in action here: http://regex101.com/r/gW3hJ8

Comment: Testing multiple whitespaces is useless since one is enough. You don't need capturing parenthesis too.

Comment: You're right on both accounts. Edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It is not even compiling... Can you update the answer @gry?

Answer (score 2):

Use [zero width lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
testString.split("(?<! ),(?! )")
```

Comment: sam_mit - please accept the answer if it was the correct one.