# Split string after comma without trailing whitespace

Tags: r, regex, string, strsplit

As the title already says, I want to split this string

```
strsplit(c("aaa,aaa", "bbb, bbb", "ddd , ddd"), ",")
```

to that

```
[[1]]
[1] "aaa" "aaa"

[[2]]
[1] "bbb, bbb"

[[3]]
[1] "ddd , ddd"
```

Thus, the regular expression has to consider that no whitespace should occur after the comma. Could be a dupe, but was not able to find a solution by googling.

Comment: The pattern has been already posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480101/regex-for-split-a-string-with-comma-ignoring-comma-with-a-space

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Only once? Then it is no dupe ;)

Comment: Since the regex usage in R is rather different than the regex usage in Java, I agree it is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> regular expression has to consider that no whitespace should occur after the comma

Use negative lookahead assertion:

```
> strsplit(c("aaa,aaa", "bbb, bbb", "ddd , ddd"), ",(?!\\s)", perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "aaa" "aaa"

[[2]]
[1] "bbb, bbb"

[[3]]
[1] "ddd , ddd"
```

`,(?!\\s)` matches `,` only if it's not followed by a space

Comment: Is there also a solution using  `perl = FALSE`?

Comment: @Jimbou Why do you ask that? What OS are you working on?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew more or less, just for curiosity. But I'm using the pattern within `tidyr`'s `separate_rows` function. Fortunately it works as expected.

Comment: @Jimbou I see that the `separate_rows` relies on `stringi` package for splitting, so it is not surprising the lookaheads are supported by the ICU regex library.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternative using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
pattern <- " , (*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,"
data <- c("aaa,aaa", "bbb, bbb", "ddd , ddd")
strsplit(data, pattern, perl = T)
```

This yields the same as above.